# updateOrCreate cause ErrorException in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model

I wrote a code to login or register users.I used updateOrCreate function to add user if not exist an update a column that is name is verifcode if user exist

**controller**

```
users Table:
id(auto increment primary key)|phone|verifcode|timeStmp
---------------------------------
    $phone=Input::get('phone');
    $code=rand(1001,9999);
    $user = new user;
    $user = array('phone'=>$phone);
    user::updateOrCreate($user,['verifcode' => $code]);
```

**Model:**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class user extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = array('phone', 'verifcode','timeStmp');
    protected $guarded = array('id');
    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    public $incrementing = false;
    const CREATED_AT= false;
    const UPDATED_AT = false;

}
```

with this code i have folowing error:
*`array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer`* that point to  `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php` file.

i just know that error point to secound argument of UpdateOrCreate function.

thanks for help

Comment: I've answered. Please check and let me know id it work for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i solve it. by adding Created_at and Update_at columns to table and adding this two coulmn to $guarded in model like this  `protected $guarded = array('id','CREATED_AT','UPDATED_AT');` and then problem fixed

thanks for help

Comment: No need to add created_at, updated_at column. Simply do false in model like:   public $timestamps = false; I suppose you have already added these 2 columns.

Comment: I also changed to false but the error was still there...i tested all the ways but only adding the column fixed it

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent), you're just using the `updateOrCreate` method wrong. Look at the flight example there.

In your case it should look like this:

```
$phone = \Input::get('phone')
$code  = rand(1001, 9999);
$user  = User::updateOrCreate(
           ['phone' => $phone],
           ['verifcode' => $code, 'timeStmp' => \Carbon::now()->timestamp]
         );
```

Comment: nothing happeend...the timeStmp has default value and dont need value

Comment: What do you want to do? From your code I understood you want to check if the user with the given phone number exists and update the code? Or do you want to check if the user with the given phone number and code exists? In that case you have a problem with your logic.

Comment: yes I want to check if the user with the given phone number exists and update the code...but error comes from that two columns...Update_at and Created_at nothing else

Answer (score 0):

If you see at the `Model` class of laravel framework code, you can note, that `updated_at` is stored only when it is not `dirty`.

```
    if (! $this->isDirty(static::UPDATED_AT)) {
        $this->setUpdatedAt($time);
    }
```

But `isDirty` method checks for nulls only.

```
public function isDirty($attributes = null)
{
    $dirty = $this->getDirty();

    if (is_null($attributes)) {
        return count($dirty) > 0;
    }

    if (! is_array($attributes)) {
        $attributes = func_get_args();
    }

    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        if (array_key_exists($attribute, $dirty)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

So just substitute `false` with `NULL`.

Comment: You'd better fix that `another error`, you made a bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$phone=Input::get('phone');
$code=rand(1001,9999);
user::updateOrCreate(
    ['phone' => $phone]
    ['verifcode' => $code]        
);
```

See if it is work for you.

Comment: thanks but i want to first check the phone not verifcode